# Mapping natively with Codename One in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-maps, codenameone

I was using the Codename Google Maps plugin with Eclipse. I added `GoogleMaps.cn1lib` to my lib and did *Menu -> CodeNameOne -> Refresh Libs*.

the code looks like :

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    hi.addComponent(new Label("Hi World"));
    MapContainer googleMap = new MapContainer();
    hi.add(googleMap);
    hi.show();
```

I have edited properties file and added the props as per instructions (replacing API keys where needed)

I have generated Google API keys and get the following exception when running the simulator. The app fails to the open street maps.

in my `lib/impl/native/android` I can see the source code in `InternalNativeMapsImp.java` for Android.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codename1.googlemaps.InternalNativeMapsImpl
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(ClassLoader.java:1001)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.findClass(ClassPathLoader.java:100)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.loadClass(ClassPathLoader.java:50)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.codename1.system.NativeLookup.create(NativeLookup.java:61)
at com.codename1.googlemaps.MapContainer.<init>(MapContainer.java:116)
at com.codename1.googlemaps.MapContainer.<init>(MapContainer.java:81)
```

I have changed IDE from Eclipse/Net Beans - same thing

and on iOS **build fails** with the same reason, just before the stack trace I have:

Executing: javac -classpath 
/var/folders/p7/xxx/classes -d /var/folders/p7/xxx/seVer 
/var/folders/p7/xxx/stub/com/codename1/googlemaps/InternalNativeMapsImplCodenameOne.java 
/var/folders/p7/xxx/stub/com/codename1/googlemaps/InternalNativeMapsStub.java 
/var/folders/p7/xxx/stub/GooglrMapsStub.java Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

How can I add the source of MapContainer to debug ?

Comment: That isn't the actual error. You probably got one of the build hints wrong. The error is further down in the logs.

Comment: I just copy/pasted the build hints indicated. In the bottom there is a link error:** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
 Ld build/GooglrMaps.build/Release-iphoneos/GooglrMaps.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GooglrMaps normal arm64
 Ld build/GooglrMaps.build/Release-iphoneos/GooglrMaps.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GooglrMaps normal armv7
(2 failures)

Comment: That isn't the error either. It's between those two. I can pretty much guarantee that the problem is in missing or miss-copied build hints. Verify that they are correct in the build hints GUI.

Comment: got it. I copied/pasted the properties from the article directly into the properties file instead of adding them. Now the build goes through, but there's no map just google logo, any hints ?

Comment: You need to fix the keys and enable the google related options in the google cloud console.

Comment: When api keys are not properly generated, instead of the map - there is only google logo. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google / Native Maps is currently available on real devices and not on simulator.

Showing openstreetmap is the default and correct behaviour, but the exception shouldn't be thrown. How are you creating your Map? The simple and right way is:

```
MapContainer googleMap = new MapContainer();
f.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, googleMap);
```

Comment: Many thanks @Diamond - my code looks the same. My IOS build fails, so I could not check on IOS, on Android - the code fails to openstreetmap. Bellow the build error snapshot:/var/folders/p7//stub/com/codename1/googlemaps/InternalNativeMapsImplCodenameOne.java /var//T//stub/com/codename1/googlemaps/InternalNativeMapsStub.java Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codename1.googlemaps.InternalNativeMapsImpl
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)

Comment: Have you updated the library from properties > update project libs